# Fetching data from a table in a range. The range is in decimal in db2

Tags: db2

I have a table in witch a clolumn have data in decimal like from -50.40 to +50.50.
So i want to get data from 30.00 to 40.32.
I wrote query like

```
select column from table where column in(30.00,40.32)
```

But this give's only the rows which have 30.00 and 40.32 values.

Comment: It doesn't appear that you bothered to even look at how the IN() predicate works.

Comment: Are either of those values _exclusive_ - that is, values really close, but not that actual value?  I ask, because if you have _more_ than 2 decimal places worth of data (or performing math that may do so), you start getting non-intuitive results with an inclusive upper bound (for a positive range).  You'd have the exact same problem [as detailed here with timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).  Always assume measurements may be more precise.  For negative ranges reverse the inclusive/exclusive bounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not giving a range but a set of values. You should define the limits

```
select column from table where column >= 30.00 and column <= 40.32
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify an inclusive range of values you can use `BETWEEN`

```
select column
  from table 
  where column between 30.00 and 40.32
```